# Singning up on tawk.to gives me an access denied error

Tags: plugins, package, tawk.to

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGoQS.png)

I am trying to add live chat on my laravel app using the tawk.to plugin but when I try to signup to get the integration code, I have the 1020 error (access denied).

Is there a way around this? I really need to use it or probably, someone should suggest another free live chat package to use for my **Laravel application**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had thesame issue when trying to use it too but I figured out they were using cloud flare to restrict some locations such as African countries like Nigeria, etc. So the fix is simple if you can change your location with VPN or use a Tor browser(which I usedin my own case) I was able to sign up and use the platform

Comment: Thank you for this brilliant idea. I just tried it and it worked out for me very well.
thanks a lot

Comment: Am glad this helped you